# Recursive java asterisk

Tags: java, recursion

i am working on what should be a relatively simple java recursion problem, though i cannot seem to find a straightforward, one-method solution anywhere.

i am trying to print out asterisks in descending followed by ascending order, so that when the user passes in 3 for example, the print out will look like this:

```
*
**
***
**
*
```

EDIT: thanks to the help of @dasblinkenlight this has evolved to:

```
public void patternMaker(int start, int max, int direction){
    if(start == 0){
        return;
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < start; i++){
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println();
    if(start == max){
        direction = -1;
    }
    patternMaker(start + direction, max, direction);
```

NOW, it prints the correct amount of asterisks, AND in the proper order:

```
*
**
***
**
*
```

thanks everyone for helping!

Comment: Psssst, the answers have direction, but if you get stuck, or are just curious, I put a solution at http://ideone.com/StJRS :)

Comment: @RayToal, appreciate the help, but i'm not sure he wants us using the Character wrapper class or importing any specific packages.

Comment: Indeed, that was just there for fun -- *wink*  Glad you noticed!  Use a loop, of course -- it is surely much faster and easier to understand than the one-line horror I threw in there. :)

Comment: @raytoal thanks for the help anyways! always good to look at more code for practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need another parameter to tell you which way you are going. You also need to test for the end condition to know when to switch from going up to going down.

```
public void patternMaker(int x, int direction){
    // Direction is either +1 or -1, depending on whether you go up or down
    // at the moment. Once you reach 3, switch the sign;
    // Once you reach zero, stop.

    // Pseudocode:
    // If x is zero, we're done
    // Print x asterisks followed by newline
    // if x == 3, make direction -1
    // Perform the recursive call with (x+direction, direction)
}
```

It would probably be easier to draw stars before recursing down, although both ways are certainly possible.

Comment: interesting, thanks for the reply! i am going to give this a shot and holler back.

Comment: so i am really liking this approach, although i can't seem to fully implement it. i now have it printing in both directions (still with one parameter), by using the loop before and after the recursive call, but it is printing opposite of how i want it. I'm not so sure how to use stackoverflow to show you my current code and print out again without posting another question, so i will shoot a link out here.

Comment: i just figured out i should just edit my original question, so the changes are above. thanks a lot!

Comment: @ohwutup Take a look at the pseudocode from the edit. Here is a [link](http://ideone.com/uINMI) to my implementation on ideone.

Comment: awesome, the only issue is that i have to check if x equals its initial value not always 3, which can't be stored in a local variable right? i am going to try adding in a third parameter that will hold the same value and check x against it.

Comment: @ohwutup No, you cannot store it in a local, because each level of recursion gets its own set of locals. If your pattern maker is a non-static method, make it an instance variable; otherwise, make it a static variable.

Comment: thanks for the help, i figured out that by putting a third parameter in for the max amount of asterisks i want on the longest line, i can check if x equals the max, then switch the direction. working code above.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure you *can* recurse with one parameter.  I think you need two.  Here's the idea:

```
stars(2, 4)
```

would print

```
**
***
****
***
**
```

and

```
stars(5, 6)
```

would print

```
*****
******
*****
```

This is naturally recursive.  Why?  Because

```
stars(n, n)
```

just prints n stars.  That is the base case.  Now how about the recursive step?  Well let's try

```
stars(k, n)
```

where k < n.  This is done like this

```
draw a line of k stars
call stars(k + 1, n)
draw a line of k stars
```

That is all.  Of course a check that k < n is good to have, but we have faith that you can figure that out.

Comment: thanks for the response, i am sure that the recursion can be done with just one parameter, but i am not sure if i know how to implement that pseudocode at the end.

Comment: If you get it with one parameter let us all know.  If you need help with the pseudocode at the end see my complete working Java solution at http://ideone.com/StJRS

Answer (score 1):

```
static String patternMaker(int x, String result){
    String curStr ="";
    for (int i=0; i<x; i++)
        curStr += "*";
    curStr += "\n";
    if (result == null){             
         return patternMaker(x-1,curStr);
    }else if (x > 0){           
          return patternMaker(x-1, curStr+result+curStr); 
    }
    else 
        return result;
}

//test with :
System.out.println(patternMaker(3,null));
```

Comment: this is the route i was looking to take from the beginning. testing now. thanks!

Answer (score -1):

```
public class pattern {

public void patternMaker(int x){
    if(x > 0){
        for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
            for(int j=0;j<=i;j++){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
        for(int i = x-1; i > 0; i--){
            for(int j=i;j>0;j--){
                System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
public static void main(String[] ar){
    new pattern().patternMaker(3);
}
}
```

Comment: The question is about recursion... It seems you missed that part.